# Database change notifications for DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

Oracle and SQL server have a database change notification feature that notifies table/row level changes in a database to registered clients. The feature is mostly used for synchronization of data with other data sources.

I've been looking for this feature in DB2 but so far, no luck. Does DB2 not provide this feature at all or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature out of the box, not in the LUW version anyway (since you reference Oracle and MS SQL Server, I guess that's what you're interested in). You can easily roll your own using Q Replication event publishing, InfoSphere Change Data Capture, or plain old triggers and MQ functions.