# Do we have anything similar "Database Change Notification" in DB2

Tags: java, events, db2, listener, db2-zos

Do we have anything similar in DB2 z/os as Database Change Notification in Oracle which could be of help to get event at java server side if any change in database .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database change notifications for DB2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979048/database-change-notifications-for-db2)

Comment: This may seem like duplicate but the answer given in the link provided by @Steeve is taking an assumption that  "(since you reference Oracle and MS SQL Server, I guess that's what you're interested in)" .I have gone through the link several times but was not of help for me with DB2. My question explicitly states that I want a solution for IBM DB z/os and not Oracle and MS SQL. The application is legacy application no provision right now provided for change in Database vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You could create triggers on Db2 for z/OS tables to notify of changes to the tables.